# Python OPC-UA access node with path

Tags: python, networking, opc, opc-ua

I am trying to connect to variables in an OPC server. I have written an application which connects by specifying the path from the root in a comma-separated-path like this:

```
PATH_TO_NODE=["0:Objects","2:Child1","2:NodeName"]
```

However, I just received details that I have to connect to the application using a "common" path like so:

```
Root\Objects\Child1//NodeName
```

or also reading from an array (I need to read the entire array)

```
Root\Objects\Child1//NodeArray/array[1]
```

How can I achieve this? I have not found any examples that show how this can be done but this should be just a formatting thing I assume.

Answer (score 1):

The "common" path format doesn't encode enough information to successfully call the `TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds` service and turn the path into a `NodeId` you can use to access Nodes.

At best you can assume everything in your "common" path is a hierarchical reference, which seems to be the same thing your comma-separated path is doing, but without knowing what namespace index each component is in you don't have enough information.

(each component is a `QualifiedName` identifying the BrowseName attribute of the next Node in the path)